# How can I launch glances when installed as a python package in the home directory?

Tags: python, monitoring

I installed [glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances) as a python package in the home directory:

```
pip install --user glances
```

How can I launch glances?

```
[me@server]$ glances
-bash: glances: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the glances github.io and it presented user install as:

```
export PYTHONUSERBASE=~/mylocalpath
pip install --user glances
```

And ensure the local path is part of your $PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/mylocalpath/bin
```

and you should be set.